# Visual Studio 2019 has errors in built-in libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, build-error

First time asking here, so please bear with me, or just let me know if I should do anything different.

I just installed a fresh version of Visual Studio 2019 and am trying to build a very basic C++ console application which includes Windows.h and iostream. Upon trying to build, I encounter over 100 build errors from the libraries that come with the IDE. Build output is shown below. Might anyone have a clue as to why the libraries that ship with VS2019 might cause so many build errors on their own?

Before you suggest Google and looking through other questions ashed here, I've searched in both places as well as Microsoft's knowledge base and have not been able to come across any relevant results. Thanks!

x32control.cpp:

```cpp
#include "common.h"

int main ()
{
    return errAndDie ("\nTesting errAndDie.\n\n");
}
```

common.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <winddi.h>


int errAndDie (const char* errorMessage) {
    std::cout << errorMessage;
    return -1;
```

common.h:

```cpp
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int errAndDie (const char *errorMessage);

#endif
```

Errors:

```
1>common.cpp
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(90,22): error C3646: 'Data1': unknown override specifier
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(90,22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(91,22): error C3646: 'Data2': unknown override specifier
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(91,22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(92,22): error C3646: 'Data3': unknown override specifier
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(92,22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(93,22): error C3646: 'Data4': unknown override specifier
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(93,22): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '['
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(93,25): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winddi.h(93,25): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\ddrawint.h(32,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GUID_MiscellaneousCallbacks'
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\ddrawint.h(32,122): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\ddrawint.h(33,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GUID_Miscellaneous2Callbacks'
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\ddrawint.h(33,124): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\ddrawint.h(34,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GUID_VideoPortCallbacks'
...
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\ddraw.h(296,44): error C3646: 'lpDDSZBufferSrc': unknown override specifier
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\ddraw.h(296,44): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>httpserver.cpp
1>x32control.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "x32control.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Without the code, I suppose nobody can answer your question..

Comment: post your "simple" code as well

Comment: It would be useful to see the first few lines of `common.cpp` to see what header files you are including and in what order.

Comment: Allow me to clarify that my code is not at all referenced in any of those errors. I can't exactly include all the lines of the code Microsoft provides in their SDK here. I will post my code in a moment as I have stepped away briefly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. Including winddi.h in common.cpp was the issue. I'm not entirely sure how that got in there, as I do not recall ever typing that and I don't copy/paste often. My apologies for not noticing this ahead of posting. Sometimes new contexts make it easier to see these things.

Comment: The issue wasn't "including `winddi.h` in `common.cpp`", the issue was *not including* `Windows.h` in `common.cpp`, you should've included both `winddi.h` and `Windows.h` inside `common.h` and include `common.h` in your `common.cpp`

Comment: Thank you. I had only deduced that was the issue because removing that include did resolve it for me. I'm rather new to C++ so I will keep that in mind down the road. Still learning how to structure things properly.